# How do I make my jpg in the jquery mobile header adjust to the size of the window its being viewed on?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am able to insert an image inside the header of the jQuery mobile data role, but when I change my browser size the jpg does not change with it. Can someone tell me a quick fix for this please?

Here is my code

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" class="page_header" >
        <img src="header_bg.jpg" >
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">   
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>   
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to fill the background of the header with your image, try this:

```
<div data-role="header" class="page_header" >
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

Use CSS for your page_header class to set the background image sized by percentage:

```
.page_header {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/1400/50/abstract/");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

> Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Fs6TQ/1/)

If you really want to use an image tag like in your example, set the width of the image to 100%:

```
.page_header img {
    width: 100%;
}
```